# Column must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function?

Tags: sql

[image]

The question is We want to sum the orders that are above $700.

Here is my code so far

```
SELECT sum(t2.amount), t1.name 
FROM Salesperson t1
INNER JOIN Orders t2 ON t1.ID  =  t2. salesperson_id
WHERE t2.amount >= 700
```

However I get an error

> Column "t1.name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or aggregate function

Why is that?

Comment: add GROUP BY t1.name at the end cause any non aggregated data should be add to the group by
it will make it as sum all the amount per each name

Comment: If you used sum, you have to specify what to sum. For example you specify t1.name to sum, amount column of rows with each ID (1 ~ 6) will be added.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images.

Comment: Did any of these answers help you?  If so, consider accepting one of the answers so that this question becomes resolved :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the fields that will be used to aggregate (group) the results, in this case the salesperson name.

```
SELECT sum(t2.amount), t1.name 
FROM Salesperson t1
INNER JOIN Orders t2 ON t1.ID  =  t2.salesperson_id
WHERE t2.amount >= 700
GROUP BY t1.name
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want just sum the amount order I think this is will work :

```
SELECT sum(t2.amount), t1.name 
FROM Salesperson t1
INNER JOIN Orders t2 ON t1.ID  =  t2. salesperson_id
GROUP BY(salesperson_id)
HAVING t2.amount >= 700;
```

The error because some salesperson_id make more than one order
so you need to group them by its id to make each rows represent the total amount order for each salesperson.
I hope this answer useful for you and fix your problem.